# Skype does not use the proximity sensor

Tags: skype, sony-xperia-neo-v, proximity-sensor

Skype does not use the proximity sensor, i.e. when I hold the phone to my ear the screen stays on and most annoyingly still responds to touch input. What may be the cause?

The sensor works fine for normal calls. I didn't find a related setting within Skype.

Comment: Which phone please?

Comment: Xperia Neo V. (I'll add the tag)